# Pandas eval() nested custom function has different behaviour with arithmetic operators and pandas wrappers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

### Intro:

I've tried to use a "nested" custom function with `pandas.eval()` but I get a some `AttributeError` with arithmetic operators, see question at the end.

I get the same result with [`Dataframe.mul()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html#pandas.DataFrame.mul) and with `*`, where both results are of type `pandas.core.series.Series`:

```py
import pandas as pd


_test = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2]})

_result_1 = _test["col1"] * 2  # type(_result_1) = <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

_result_2 = _test["col1"].mul(2)  # type(_result_2) = <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I can use the arithmetic operator:

```py
_test["new_col_1"] = _test.eval("col1 * 2")
```

The use of the custom function is possible:

```py
def cumsum_function_test(input_series):
    return input_series.cumsum()

_test["new_col_4"] = _test.eval("@cumsum_function_test(col1)")
```

The usage of pandas wrapper operators (e.g. [`Dataframe.mul()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html#pandas.DataFrame.mul)) inline or with a custom function is possible:

```py
def cumsum_function_test(input_series):
    return input_series.cumsum()

_test["new_col_2"] = _test.eval("col1.mul(2).cumsum()")

_test["new_col_5"] = _test.eval("@cumsum_function_test(col1.mul(2))")
```

### Question:

But I get an `AttributeError` in this case:

```py
_test["new_col_6"] = _test.eval("@cumsum_function_test(col1 * 2)") # => AttributeError: 'BinOp' object has no attribute 'value'
```

How can I handle the equation `col1 * 2` in order to use it in the custom function?

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also have same problem. I resolved in-direct method. This problem take place when custom function inputs have arithmetic expression. But a custom function can get another functions as input. So, I defined Plus, Minus, Mult, Divd then use e.g. df.eval("@custom_func(@Mult(col1, 2))")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new_col_1 as a proxy.

```
_test["new_col_6"] = _test.eval("@cumsum_function_test(new_col_1)")
```

**output**

```
   col1  new_col_1  new_col_4  new_col_2  new_col_5  new_col_6
0     1          2          1          2          2          2
1     2          4          3          6          6          6
```

Comment: Thank you but I actually don't want to create an extra column for my use case. I only used the column names to visualize my problem / different behaviour.